# Is there a simple way to convert a NodeJS KeyObject to a Buffer?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, ed25519

I am using NodeJS to generate Ed25519 keypairs. I need to convert the public key to a custom character encoding. However, there seems to be no way to convert the `KeyObject`s returned by the `crypto.generateKeyPair()` to buffers.

Does the standard library offer a way to directly generate the keys as buffers instead of `KeyObject`s?

Comment: I was just wondering how your are parsing the asymmetric key to a buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KeyObject offers a `.export()` method that will give you a string or a buffer.  It seems you can use that method to convert your KeyObjects and can then apply your custom encoding.

https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_keyobject_export_options

You can get it to directly generate as a buffer/string only if you specify the `publicKeyEncoding` and/or `privateKeyEncoding`.  But, if you're using a non-supported, custom encoding, then you can't get it to do that.  You can export it to a Buffer/String and then apply your custom encoding to that.

From the doc for the API:

> If a publicKeyEncoding or privateKeyEncoding was specified, this
> function behaves as if keyObject.export() had been called on its
> result. Otherwise, the respective part of the key is returned as a
> KeyObject.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that for asymmetric keys `.export()` can only output PEM or DER. My current solution is to parse the outputted key, which is pretty inelegant but it works

Comment: please post your version of the code @adrian